# C# Using sql parameters which now won't work

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, parameters

Hey I was using parametrized queries for my application which worked just fine but now (I don't know why) they aren't replaced anymore with the values...

So instead of running something like `"SELECT [TABLE_NAME] FROM [MyDefinetelyExistingDatabase]";` it tries to execute `"SELECT [TABLE_NAME] FROM [@targetDatabase]";` which, of course, will fail.

```
 var dataBaseToGetTablesFrom = "MyDefinetelyExistingDatabase";
 var results = new List<string>();

        const string query = @"SELECT
                                    [TABLE_NAME] AS tableName
                                FROM 
                                    [@targetDatabase].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] ;";
        
        using (var context = new ConnectionHandler(true))
        {
            if (context.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                throw new ConnectionFailedException(context.Connection.State);

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, context.Connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@targetDatabase", dataBaseToGetTablesFrom);

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                        return results.ToArray();

                    while (reader.Read())
                        results.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        return results.ToArray();
```

I now tried different formats and things to add the parameters but it results in the same...
I don't want to do this by inserting the values into the query directly via `string.Format` eg but I want to have those parameters (which work properly at different places in the code (???) but not where I want.

In fact, I need to use parameters in every statement and must be able to address different databases by calling them like [DB].[Table-Schema].[Table]

[EDIT]

Hey guys, figured the problem some days ago and thought I share it with you.
As far as I have noticed, my problem at the whole was to try to replace the databasename and / or in some other examples, the table name as well.
So this won't work which makes clearly sense to me as the server can't prepare to execute a statement if it doesn't even know on which table it should work and therefore doesn't know anything about the structure etc.

So I changed my statements to fit my new knowledge and it worked as expected like a charm.

Comment: @lad2025 You cannot use a `variable` in the `USE` statement also `GO` is not  `t-sql` , it only works in `SSMS` as a `batch separator`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should read this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @M.Ali Yup so as always we come back to Dynamic-SQL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need dynamic sql for this something like.....

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT [TABLE_NAME] AS tableName '
         + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@targetDatabase) + N'.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response
It seems like a lot of work for a simple query, it must be easier to execute a paramet

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `ConnectionHandler` is, but if that is your own code you can implement it with [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to use a variable to assign the `InitialCatalog` instead of putting the database name in the query. This would be preferable to dynamic sql which requires careful sanitization.

Comment: This means opening a new connection to query against each database, to me this seems a bit of a overkill for a fairly simple task :S

Comment: @M.Ali - I disagree, opening a new connection for each query is the preferred and recommended way of executing ADO.NET queries. Sql Server will handle connection pooling so the expensive act of actually creating new connections is abstracted from your code. In short, I agree with Crowcoder on this, it will eliminate the need to check your database name parameters and it could also help you generate better error messages should the database not exist, you misspell it, you don't have access rights, etc.

Comment: @M.Ali connection pooling maintains efficient use of connections.